# UIbutton tap crash inside uipageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uipageviewcontroller

I have a AViewController, and it has a nib. File's Owner of the nib is AViewController. 
Inside this view I have a UIButton. UIButton has a tap action which calls AViewController's buttonTapped:(id)sender method. 
And I have a UIPageViewcontroller which sets AViewController as the ViewController.

If I push or present UIPageViewController and tap on the button. Works fine. 
If I manually add view of UIPageViewController inside rootViewController's view and tap on the button, it crashes.

Any ideas why?

Code snipped:

```
    PViewController *p = [PViewController new];
    // P is the UIPageViewController and it has AViewController in it. 
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:p animated:YES completion:nil];
    // Tapping on AViewController's button works fine. 


    PViewController *p = [PViewController new];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view addSubview:p.view];
    // Adding PageViewControllers view inside rootViewController then tapping on button does not work.
```

Comment: Show the crash message from the debug console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PViewController *p = [PViewController new];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view
    addSubview:p.view];
```

That is illegal. You cannot simply add a view controller's view directly to another view controller's view.

In order to perform that kind of move, you must go through an entire song-and-dance in which one view controller is made the child view controller of the other, and certain messages are sent in a certain order.

See Apple's documentation on this topic:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6

Comment: And here is the relevant section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers

Comment: That comment helped a lot. Very useful.